# Device xxx_init not getting called

Tags: c, dll, windows-ce

I  wrote a simple stream driver to learn device drivers, in that i am just having DLLEntry, Init and DeInit functions and also I have exported all the functions in a .def file .

I also added the registry settings for the driver in HKLM/Drivers/Sample.

I wrote a application to test its working, where i called ActivateDeviceEx with the following path .

My DLLEntry function is getting called, but Init function is not getting called. I am using RETAILMSG macros to print the debug information.

I also have seen the post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621894/device-driver-not-calling-xxx-init) where he is also facing the same issue

But i dont understood what we have to do for it to work...

Comment: Did you check out the answer given in your mentioned post ?

Comment: There is nothing like an answer there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that DllEntry gets called but Init does not hints at an issue with the function exports. A stream driver [must export at least the following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms895459.aspx):

- Init
- Deinit
- Open
- Close
- Read
- Write
- Seek
- IOControl

Also, unless the Flags value in the registry includes DEVFLAGS_NAKEDENTRIES, each function must be prefixed with the device name, so if the driver supports, say, an XYZ device, the functions must be named XYZ_Init, XYZ_Deinit, etc.

Comment: I have only implemented Init and DeInit and was trying to just call createFile API from Windows will it not be sufficient. Is there any requirement that we have to implement all the above functions in the driver...

Comment: According to the linked article, yes it is a requirement that all these functions be implemented. For instance, CreateFile requires that the driver supports XXX_Open. Actually there's not much to adding a series of one-line functions that simply return a 'success' value, and it would be a good first step towards a fully-functioning driver. The XXX_Open function indicates success by returning a non-zero value. Check the linked MSDN article for details on the other functions.